# Rails: How to use instance method in Active Record Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, instance

I am having a filter query which should return all the records where either

1. attribute (column) "status" is not "done", or
2. instance method "completeness_status" does not return "done"

The query is something like that:
`Studies.where("studies.status != ? OR studies.completeness_status != ?", "done", "done")`
but I am getting error that column completeness_status does not exist.

Unfortunately, the column status is not continuously updated, so I cannot use it only. Also, the instance method "completeness_status" is based on records from other tables.
I try to add a scope to my model and use this instance method as scope but also I was not successful.
Also, I tried to used it as class method but then I do not know how to call it from where clause.

```
def self.completeness_status(study)
 # code
end
```

or

```
def self.completeness_status_done?(study)
 # code return true or false
end
```

Any Idea how to solve that.
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use an instance method in a query but if you provide the necessary logic maybe that could be converted to be part of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use instance methods inside your query. But if you like to check the condition of completeness for only one row, then you can use it as instance method:

```rb
first_study = Study.first
first_study.completeness_status_done?
```

Also, if you provide more information about what is going on inside your `completeness_status_done?` then maybe I can give you some ideas to use scopes.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html